# Убрать разрыв блока на странице при печати

Tags: html, css, media-queries, print

[image: печать]

Сначала пытался сделать на текущей странице, но решив что какие-то стили мешают,
оставил только эти свойства на родительском элементе и на самих блоках, которые не нужно разрывать, однако и это не помогает.

```
.print-parent{
   page-break-inside:auto;
}
.print-children{
   page-break-inside:avoid;
   page-break-after:auto;
 }
```

Как видно на картинке блок делится на две страницы, а должен по идеи переносится полностью на вторую страницу. Элементы блочные.

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте в `css @media print` настроить свои стили при печати

Comment: в @media print я это все делал. Так что не помогает. Другие стили применяются